# Upgrade to 23.10. Grub finds my Windows disk and assumes it is a UEFI installation, even though Ubuntu is running BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Upgraded from 23.04 to 23.10 when Discover asked me if I wanted to upgrade.

On-line update worked well and it rebooted into Ubuntu 23.10.
However there is no Grub menu at all, so I can't boot into Windows.
The weird thing is that Grub finished with:

```
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

But Ubuntu is running on the old MBR/BIOS.

```
ls /sys/firmware/efi/*

ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi/': No such file or directory**
```

So if Ubuntu knows the system is running MBR, why does Grub say:

`Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings` ...??

Just to make sure I installed gdisk and got:

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present*
```

For both the Ubuntu disk and the disk with Windows installed.
Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. There is a boot menu entry added which will make it possible to enter the firmware settings (in earlier days you called it BIOS) from the grub menu. It has nothing to do with UEFI vs legacy boot mode.

Comment: Well, the problem is that:

- There is no Grub menu, it boots directly into 23.10

- Whether it is a case of Grub mistaking the Windows disk for a UEFI disk or not (it is not), I can't boot into Windows.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494670/edit) your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` to your question.

Comment: By default grub should unhide the boot menu if a dual boot is detected (which is obviously the case) even if timeout is set to zero. Did you make any changes to `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` or `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to hide the boot menu permanently?

Answer (score -1):

Please, edit `/etc/default/grub` file, by replacing the lines containing `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT` like this:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=6
```

See, [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) for more details.